# Crostini Built-In Camera Support?

Tags: linux, camera, built-in, chromebook, crostini

I was trying to get my built-in camera working on my chromebook for my linux vm. I saw that there was a usb device that I could connect to linux which was "HP Wide Vision HD Camera". I assume this is the built-In camera that came on the chromebook. When I enable it, it comes up as a usb devices after using lsusb. However, I couldn't find a /dev/video* path so that I could use it.

Is there no full support yet or is there another way I can get it to work?

Comment: Pls let me know which linux flavour you are using like (Ubuntu, arch, suse) also the emulation software (oracle virtualbox). It would be helpful for us to check further.

Comment: I'm running Debian Bullseye. I'm not sure of the exact software but it is the native [linux](https://chromeos.dev/en/linux) machine that can be installed on newer Chromebooks.